# How to control browser confirmation dialog on leaving page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are a lot of questions regarding this but nothing is answering me right. I want to show a confirmation dialog when user leaves the page. If the user press Cancel he will stay on page and if OK the changes that he has made will be rollback-ed by calling a method. I have done like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  var r = confirm( "Do you want to leave?" );
  if (r == true) {
       //I will call my method
  }
  else {
      return false;
  }
};
```

The problem is that I am getting the browser default popup: "LeavePage / StayOnPage"

> This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you
>   have entered may not be saved.

This message is shown in Firefox, in Chrome is a little different. I get this popup after I press OK on my first confirmation dialog.

Is there a way not to show this dialog? (the second one, that I did not create).
Or if there is any way to control this popup, does anyone know how to do that?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I override the OnBeforeUnload dialog and replace it with my own?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own)

Comment: Thanks but please read for one moment my whole question, I have read all the other questions here before posting this

Comment: I am getting a problem! Can you help me with that?

Comment: The answer to that question is the answer to yours. You may not like the outcome, but it's still the only answer.

Comment: Previous versions of Firefox was letting to override `window.onbeforeunload`..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's what I've done, modify to fit your needs:

```
// This default onbeforeunload event
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return "Do you want to leave?"
}

// A jQuery event (I think), which is triggered after "onbeforeunload"
$(window).unload(function(){
    //I will call my method
});
```

Note: it's tested to work in Google Chrome, IE8 and IE10.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this is not working.. The behavior in this case is the same. Maybe I am doing something wrong. I tried to put an alert within the "$(window).unload(function()" but it is not shown. Any idea?

Comment: Well, `$(window).unload` is only called when the user accepts to leave the page. Depending on what browser you're using for testing, it'll behave differently. For instance, Chrome will block alerts in the unload-function. So try with a `console.log` instead, and see if that gives you some output.

Answer (score 3):

This is simple. Just use

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return '';
};
```

to prompt when the user reloads, and

```
window.close = function(){
 return '';
};
```

to prompt when the user closes the page.
But the user have to click on the page once, or do anything on the page for the code to detect. You don't have to put anything the the `return'';`, because JavaScript interpreter would just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {
       if (data_needs_saving()) {
           return "Do you really want to leave our brilliant application?";
       } else {
          return;
       }
    };
```