# Don't allow user to close window for incomplete form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a big form on jsp page where user enters some information.

My requirement is that if user move away to another link or close window, I should alert that "Your form changes will be lost if you move away from screen, please press save before moving away from this screen." If user press ok, we should navigate to next page else stay on same page.

How can I achieve this? Any javascript method available for this? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179514/how-to-control-browser-confirmation-dialog-on-leaving-page You need to manipulate as per your requirement

Comment: Here is **[another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443503/how-to-run-javascript-code-on-window-close)**

Comment: Thanks all, I was searching only for form, hence couldn't found all these question. Although my question is not duplicate but onbeforeunload method will surely do my job. Thanks