# window.location.reload() not working for Firefox

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, firefox, reload

I am trying to refresh the page on click function.

```
reloadPage(){
 this._$window.location.reload();
 this._$window.onbeforeunload = null;
}
```

Above code is working fine in Chrome and IE. But in Firefox getting prompt message saying **this page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved**.

How to prevent this in Firefox?

Note: Without Jquery.

Comment: have you tried this? [How to control browser confirmation dialog on leaving page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179514/how-to-control-browser-confirmation-dialog-on-leaving-page_

Comment: @moghya, there also it is working in Chrome & IE. They didn't mention about Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the set time out function and i expect it'll work in any situation and in any browser. Please have a look at below code snippet.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  window.location.reload();
});
```

**or simply:**

```
setTimeout(location.reload)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should allow you to reload without a prompt:

```
window.location.href = window.location;
```

See pen:
https://codepen.io/ndcunningham/pen/mjpdEE?editors=1111